# Contact Form 7 adding custom calculation into notification email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I embedded contact form 7 on my site. Basically what I want is, customer fills in my form (name, gross income, loan amount, loan term etc), then all form information goes to me and a response email back to customer with some calculations(e.g result1 = loan amount/loan term). How can I add result1 into the response email?

Comment: I finally found a solution: http://xaviesteve.com/3298/wordpress-contact-form-7-hook-unofficial-developer-documentation-and-examples/. To get data or save data, use $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['FieldName'].

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem over here... I made a dirty(!) fix by adding a new field in the form and set in on hidden. With js or other script I set the value of the hidden input field.

In my notification email, I just add the hidden field.

I know it's dirty! :-)

Grtz.